# Unity: Why can I not control the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm following this intro tutorial on how to get started building games for the Oculus using Unity: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-tutorial/

I have added the floor and four walls. I have also added the sphere Player object.

Finally, I have added the PlayerController script to the player obejct.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int speed = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        // get input data from keyboard or controller
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        // update player position based on input
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x += moveHorizontal * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        position.y += moveVertical * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

The tutorial says:

> At this point if you preview your game in the Game View by pressing the Play button, you’ll find you can control the Player with the arrow keys or W-A-S-D on your keyboard.

However, after pressing player, I find that I cannot control the player. Neither the cursor keys or W-A-S-D work.

Have I missed anything obvious? Is there some additional setup I need to do before hand?

Comment: Have you set your speed value to anything?

Comment: No! It works when I set a value in the inspector.

Comment: Btw if you don't use `Start` better remove it completely. It is called by Unity as message and only causes unnecessary overhead

Answer (score -1):

Speed value is set to zero by default, be sure to edit this value in inspector and not in Play mode since it does not get saved there.